# Sonarqube-4.0 Issue while setting up in linux machine (linux-x86-32)

Tags: linux, sonarqube

**Please find the error Below**

"ERROR o.o.c.ConsumerManager  Nonce verification failed. "

"WARN  o.s.p.o.OpenIdClient  Fail to verify OpenId request: Nonce verification failed."

Error while opening in the browser

**http://:/openid/unauthorized**

how to fix this issue please suggest...

My main intension is do i miss any jars in the lib

The tree structure of lib in sonarqube-4.0

**sonarqube-4.0/lib/**

**|-- bundled-plugins**

|   |-- sonar-checkstyle-plugin-1.4.jar

|   |-- sonar-findbugs-plugin-1.4.jar

|   |-- sonar-jacoco-plugin-1.4.jar

|   |-- sonar-java-plugin-1.4.jar

|   |-- sonar-pmd-plugin-1.4.jar

|   |-- sonar-squid-java-plugin-1.4.jar

|   `-- sonar-surefire-plugin-1.4.jar

|-- commons-io-2.4.jar

**|-- core-plugins**

|   |-- sonar-core-plugin-4.0.jar

|   |-- sonar-cpd-plugin-4.0.jar

|   |-- sonar-dbcleaner-plugin-4.0.jar

|   |-- sonar-design-plugin-4.0.jar

|   |-- sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.0.jar

|   |-- sonar-l10n-en-plugin-4.0.jar

|   `-- sonar-maven-batch-plugin-4.0.jar

|-- jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar

|-- logback-access-1.0.13.jar

|-- logback-classic-1.0.13.jar

|-- logback-core-1.0.13.jar

|-- slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

|-- sonar-application-4.0.jar

|-- tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar

|-- tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.42.jar

|-- tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.42.jar

`-- wrapper-3.2.3.jar

The Extensions Plugins tree structure is

**sonarqube-4.0/extensions/plugins/**

|-- README.txt

|-- sonar-build-breaker-plugin-1.1.jar

|-- sonar-checkstyle-plugin-1.4.jar

|-- sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.4.jar

|-- sonar-cutoff-plugin-0.2.jar

|-- sonar-findbugs-plugin-1.4.jar

|-- sonar-jacoco-plugin-1.4.jar

|-- sonar-java-plugin-1.4.jar

|-- sonar-openid-plugin-1.2.jar

|-- sonar-pmd-plugin-1.4.jar

|-- sonar-scm-activity-plugin-1.5.1.jar

|-- sonar-squid-java-plugin-1.4.jar

`-- sonar-surefire-plugin-1.4.jar

Comment: What's in your SQ_HOME/extensions/plugins directory? This looks like a misconfiguration of the OpenID plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a misconfiguration of the [OpenID plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/OpenID+Plugin). Please check that your settings are correct (especially the `sonar.openid.*Url` settings).